# In the terminology terminal, how do I change it's login shell?

Tags: terminal, elementary-os, bodhi

I would like to use `tcsh` and not `bash`.

I tried `chsh`, but it still is logging me in as `bash`

*Terminology is the default terminal for Bodhi Linux*

Answer (score 1):

chsh changes the login shell, that information goes to the `/etc/passwd` file. GUI terminal emulators don't use that value in general, instead they have their own settings where you can specify which shell to call.

Without using Terminology I don't know which exact setting you'll have to change, but it should be in its Preferences dialog.

Comment: Most terminal software just uses the value of the environment variable `$SHELL`. I don't think it's common to have an actual preference instead. If the OP has changed their login shell then `$SHELL` will reflect that, but only after logging out and back in.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected then. I've been using Konsole almost exclusively and I shouldn't have assumed it was the same for other emulators. It should be fairly simple to check if Terminology is honoring the value of $SHELL by starting it as SHELL=/bin/tcsh terminology